# Template for cleaning up on vector destruction - how to?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement a template which would allow to create a class derived from vector<> such that on deletion the element of the vector are deleted. The below snippet represents an attempt to do so:

```
include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class P>
class TidyVector : public vector<P> {
 public:
  ~TidyVector() {
    while (vector<P>::size()) {
      P pi = vector<P>::back();
      vector<P>::pop_back();
      delete pi;
    }
  }
}

TidyVector<int*> i;
```

Attempts to compile this using g++ -c try.cc result in the following error messages:

```
try.cc:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token
try.cc:6: error: expected template-name before '<' token
try.cc:6: error: expected `{' before '<' token
try.cc:6: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
try.cc:17: error: aggregate 'TidyVector<int*> i' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

What is going on - why does this not work? Or, maybe, a more appropriate question to ask: what is the standard way to deal with this situation (automated clean up of the vector on deletion)?

Comment: Come on, that error is obvious to fix. Doing templates, you should know how to fix it, really :)

Comment: ok, I goofed up with the sample code, I hastily created a sample to demonstrate the error. when I correct the first lines to 

using namespace std;
#include <vector>

I still get an error:

try.cc:18: error: invalid declarator before 'i'

and this is what I was trying to figure out

Comment: That one is the semi-colon you left off the class end of the class.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that is supposed to be #include < vector >. So that's one bug.

Second, you should avoid inheriting from vector, it doesn't have a virtual destructor, so your class could get easily cast to a standard vector and your destructor not run.

(oh, and you left the semi colon off the class end)

Third, have you considered just doing vector< boost::shared_ptr< some_class > > instead?

Clarifying a bit on why shared_ptr approach is better: Your class right now only cleans things up in one instance; if they are still there when the class is destructed. But say you have a TidyVector foo with 10 elements and then someone does:

```
foo[5] = new int; // Memory leak!
```

Or

```
foo.resize(0); // Memory leak!
```

Or

```
foo.erase(foo.begin()); // Memory leak!
```

The list goes on

Comment: Oh, this is embarrassing- too many things went wrong with this question, but thank you for your answer and suggestions!

Comment: oh, hold on. seems like you've already said anything i wanted to write in my answer. +1 of course. haha :p

Answer (score 4):

There is already a class that does this: [Boost's ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html). I suggest checking it out, and looking at how they did it. Short answer: they don't use inheritance, they use composition.

Answer (score 1):

Read the compiler error messages: You're missing a '#' from #include, for starters.

In the your destructor, you don't need to specify `vector<P>::` - you are deriving from the vector, so call its methods without qualification, e.g. size() etc.

The vector will clean up its own storage so you don't need to call pop_back() on it. Try

```
for (iterator i = begin(); i != end; ++i)
    delete *i;
```

Instead of doing this manually, you cold hold a smart pointer such as shared_ptr in your vector, the elements would then be deleted for you without needing a derived class.

There are differing opinions on whether deriving from standard library containers is a good idea, a search here will point you to several discussions on the issue.

Comment: well, I started without qualifiers, this is what I get when compiling:

try.cc: In destructor 'TidyVector<P>::~TidyVector()':
try.cc:10: error: there are no arguments to 'size' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'size' must be available
try.cc:10: error: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)

Comment: @Vadim, you are right, you have to make the call depend on a template parameter. you may do that using vector<P>::size() or this->size(); ("this" has type TidyVector<P>*, and so it depends implicitly on P too)